# How can I do a Repeater of an Entity?

Tags: qt, qml

In QML, I want to iterate through a list and instantiate an [`Entity`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-core-entity.html) .   Currently, I'm using a [`Repeater`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html), but it appears that an `Entity` is not a `Component`.

I've tried the following

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
import QtPositioning 5.2;
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.9
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.0

Flickable {
  id: flickable;

  ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
    background: Rectangle {
      border.width:1
      border.color: 'gray';
      color: "#00000000";
      radius: 4;
    }
  }

  Scene3D {
    id: scene3d
    anchors.margins: 1;
    anchors.left: parent.left;
    anchors.top: parent.top;
    height: 600;
    width: 600;

    focus: true
    onActiveFocusChanged: {
      console.log('flickable.interactive',flickable.interactive);
      flickable.interactive = !activeFocus;
    }
    aspects: ["input", "logic"]
    cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

    Entity {
      id: sceneRoot

      Camera {
        id: camera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: 1 // 16/9
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d( 255, 255, 700.0 )
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 128, 128, 0.0 )
      }

      OrbitCameraController {
        camera: camera
      }

      components: [
        RenderSettings {
          activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
            clearColor: Qt.rgba(1, 1, 1, 1)
            camera: camera
          }
        },
        // Event Source will be set by the Qt3DQuickWindow
        InputSettings { }
      ]

      PhongMaterial {
        id: material
      }

      Entity {
          Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log('Entity completed.');
          }
          ExtrudedTextMesh { id: ex_label; text: 'Example'; depth: 0.1}
          Transform{ id: ex_label_transform; translation: Qt.vector3d(128 - 10, 128, 0); scale3D: Qt.vector3d(20,20,20); }

          components: [ex_label, material, ex_label_transform];
        }


      Repeater {
        model: [{name:'foo'}]
        Entity {
          Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log('Entity completed.');
          }
          ExtrudedTextMesh { id: label; text: 'Index' + index; depth: 0.1}
          Transform{ id: label_transform; translation: Qt.vector3d(128 + index*10, 128, 0); scale3D: Qt.vector3d(20,20,20); }

          components: [label, material, label_transform];
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Which yields:
[image]

I expected to see some other extruded text of `Index 0`, to no avail.

How can I get the equivalent of a `Repeater` for instantiating `Entities`?

### My Workaround

```
Entity {
  PhongAlphaMaterial { id: phong_mat_0; ambient: '#000'; alpha: model_list.length > 0 ? 0.8 : 0;}
  ExtrudedTextMesh { id: label_0; text: 'Index 0'; depth: 0.1}
  Transform{ id: label_transform_0; translation: Qt.vector3d(128 + 0*10, 128, 0); scale3D: Qt.vector3d(20,20,20); }
  components: [label_0, phong_mat_0, label_transform_0];
}

Entity {
  PhongAlphaMaterial { id: phong_mat_1; ambient: '#000'; alpha: model_list.length >1 ? 0.8 : 0;}
  ExtrudedTextMesh { id: label_1; text: 'Index 1'; depth: 0.1}
  Transform{ id: label_transform_1; translation: Qt.vector3d(128 + 1*10, 128, 0); scale3D: Qt.vector3d(20,20,20); }
  components: [label_1, phong_mat_1, label_transform_1];
}

Entity {
  PhongAlphaMaterial { id: phong_mat_2; ambient: '#000'; alpha: model_list.length >2 ? 0.8 : 0;}
  ExtrudedTextMesh { id: label_2; text: 'Index 2'; depth: 0.2}
  Transform{ id: label_transform_2; translation: Qt.vector3d(128 + 2*10, 128, 0); scale3D: Qt.vector3d(20,20,20); }
  components: [label_2, phong_mat_2, label_transform_2];
}
```

Comment: Instantiator is worth a shot.

Comment: [`Instantiator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html) did work _better_, because I  the "'Entity completed." messages from the looped through model, but it still doesn't display.   I guess I'll do a manual loop-unrolling hack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Repeater` only works with `Item`, which an `Entity` is not.

Since a `Scene3D` is not your usual quick scene, you need to have a repeater/view that is aware of it to instantiate objects inside it.

[`NodeInstantiator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-core-nodeinstantiator.html) is the equivalent of a `Repeater` for 3D Nodes ( it will reparent its dynamically created objects to its parent).

This concept of specific repeater is also used with `Map` and `MapItemView`.